# How to perform httpOnly cookie authentication via proxies?

Tags: javascript, authentication, cookies, http-headers, httponly

I have client on localhost on port `8080` lets call it `A`. I have a backend API on localhost on port `3002` lets call it `C`. `A` doesn't connect to `C` directly, but via a secure tunnel with HTTPS, lets call it `B`. So the process is like this:

```
A: http://localhost:8080 =>
B: https://localtunnel.me/some-id =>
C: http://localhost:3002
```

The problem is that if `A` configures `withCredentials: true`, the `httpOnly` cookies won't be pass through the proxy - it would only work if `A` was talking directly with `C`.

How to make it work, or that I am doing something wrong.

Comment: All connection HTTPS?

Comment: @ikhvjs I don't understand..

Comment: A to B is HTTTPS, how about B to C? Is it also HTTPS?

Comment: No, B to C is from HTTPs to my localhost which is on HTTP.

Comment: Did you set the `secure` flag in the cookie?

Comment: I set only when production, so basically this is the problem? (its configured to false for your question)

Comment: Yes. I think cookie with `secure` flag will not send through HTTP. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#restrict_access_to_cookies

Comment: But I the secure flag is on false..

Comment: Ah, sorry, you are sending to localhost, the secure flag should not the issue. Do you have access in B? If so, did you get the cookie from it?

Comment: No, I don't have access to B